# Searching between two numbers(prices) in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to run an eloquent query to filter results by category, then title, then price. category and title work as they should but when i added BETWEEN for searching between two prices it broke. Does anyone know how i could fix my query?

```
@foreach(Inventory::where('category', '=', $cat)->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $search_query .'%')->where('price', 'BETWEEN', $min_price, 'AND', $max_price)->get() as $search_results)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for `whereBetween()`. First, put the Eloquent query in your controller:

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('category', $cat)
    ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search_query . '%')
    ->whereBetween('price', [$min_price, $max_price])
    ->get();
```

Then, pass the `$inventory` variable to your view:

```
return view('my.view.path', compact('inventory'));
```

Finally, in your view, you can loop through the results:

```
@foreach($inventory as $search_results)
```

See the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) for more info.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I would had never realized there was a whereBetween for eloquent. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Brandon Glad to help :)